# How can i merge the word documents when there are images in the table columns?

Tags: docx4j

first document-2 images,second document table has images in the first column.Want to merge these two documents into a single document?

Comment: Please clean up your question, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: See reply to your cross post at http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/docx4j-t2501.html   I suggest you delete this question.